# Add form option in sonata admin class

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

How can I add custom option to  formmMapper in sonata admin class?

I have form related to entity in admin class. For some reason I want to add my own options to one of the field

```
    $formMapper
        ->with('tab.dimension')
            ->add('dimension', 'collection', array(
                'type' => 'dimension_product',

                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'my_custom_options' => false,
            ))
        ->end();
```

Unfortunatly it is not possible in this way,because this options isn't defined in resolver.
But I have no access to resolver in "normal way".
Sonata defined form builder in two methods:

```
public function getFormBuilder()
{
    $this->formOptions['data_class'] = $this->getClass();

    $formBuilder = $this->getFormContractor()->getFormBuilder(
        $this->getUniqid(),
        $this->formOptions
    );

    $this->defineFormBuilder($formBuilder);

    return $formBuilder;
}


public function defineFormBuilder(FormBuilder $formBuilder)
{
    $mapper = new FormMapper($this->getFormContractor(), $formBuilder, $this);

    $this->configureFormFields($mapper);

    foreach ($this->getExtensions() as $extension) {
        $extension->configureFormFields($mapper);
    }

    $this->attachInlineValidator();
}
```

Allowed options are defined in this  object:

```
 new FormMapper($this->getFormContractor(), $formBuilder, $this);
```

Could somebody give me advice how can i add my own option?

Answer (score 1):

Little bit late to the party,  but it sort of depends on what you want to do with this option.

If you need to add a real custom form option, it is not very much different from working directly with Symfony forms.  You can add extra options and functionality to a given form type using a [form extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html)  . You could even add functionality to the sonata form types this way.

If you simply need to pass an option from one Admin to a child Admin (which I think you might want to do),  you can use the field description options  rather than the actual form options:

```
$formMapper
        ->with('tab.dimension')
            ->add('dimension', 'collection', array(
                'type' => 'dimension_product',

                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'required' => false,
            ), array(
                'my_custom_options' => false,
            ))
->end();
```

Now in your child Admin you can retrieve these options using

```
$this->getParentFieldDescription()->getOptions();
```

To be used to configure your child Admin.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i can't check out is it solve my problem. I didn't use sonata for about one year.   So I can't assign your answer as correct.